# Haskell Qualified Imports (Creating an Empty Set)

Tags: haskell, set

I am attempting to pass back a Node type from this function, but I get the error that `empty` is out of scope:

```
import Data.Set (Set)  
import qualified Data.Set as Set

data Node = Vertex String (Set Node)  
    deriving Show

toNode :: String -> Node  
toNode x = Vertex x empty
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`import qualified Data.Set as Set` means that when you want to use something from `Data.Set`, you have to qualify it with `Set.`. So to use `empty` write `Set.empty`.

Comment: Should I have both of those import statements? I just took it from example code.

Comment: The first imports the type Set unqualified (so you don't have to write `Set.Set` in type signatures), but nothing else. The second import allows you to use everything else from `Data.Set` by qualifying it with `Set.`. People generally do it this way (as opposed to importing everything unqualified) to avoid name collisions with Prelude functions (like `map`, `filter` etc.).